# Core Data & Decode: Go one hierarchy step further in json

Tags: ios, json, swift, core-data, decode

My Api(json) looks like this:

```
"timezone": "America/Los_Angeles",
"currently": {
    "time": 1534941429,
    ...
},
```

With my code I can access the timezone as following:

```
timezone = try container.decode(Double.self, forKey: .timezone)
```

But how can I dig into the hierarchy of my json file and access the time?

Comment: What does this have to do with Core Data?

Comment: Without Core Data I wouldn't even need to initialize a container and decode it from there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
let currently = try container.nestedContainer(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self, forKey: .currently)
time = try currently.decode(Int.self, forKey: .time)
```

This was all it needed. Hope this helps anyone.

Answer (score 0):

```
    struct Currently: Codable {
      let time: Int
    ...
    }

    let myStructDictionary = try container.decode([String: Currently].self, from: json)
myStructDictionary.forEach { print("\($0.key): \($0.value)") }
```

Hope this helps.